while searching a string doesn't work as expected
I check a file that have names with wildcards. I need to compare a variable with these names.
To do that. I do:
while read -r LineExc; do
   if [[ "${job}" == ${LineExc} ]]; then
     echo "found"
     excepcion=yes
   else
     echo "not found"
   fi
done < exceptions.cfg

The exceptions have:
car*
house

So if job variable with value house, it goes to not found, but it should go to found.
Any help please?

You need to use an operator other than == — you should be using =~, I believe.

Also, you may want to match the entire string with ^"${LineExc}"$. And by using "${LineExc}" within double quotes, you ensure that any special characters in LineExc are treated literally and not as part of the pattern matching syntax.

@MilosStojanovic — quoting ${LineExc} defeats the object of the exercise, assuming that the line cars* should match any name starting cars.

@JonathanLeffler yeah, just wanted to get it out there so the OP is aware of that.

They specifically said that the file contains wildcards, so they want them treated as patterns, not literals.

@MilosStojanovic You're confusing regular expression with wildcards. ^ and $ have no special meaning in wildcards. And wilcards are automatically anchored.

@JonathanLeffler =~ matches a regular expression, not glob.

You're echoing not found if it doesn't match the current line. But it could match a different line. E.g. It echoes not found for the car* line, but matches the house line.

Move not found out of the loop. After the loop, check if excepcion is set; if not, no match was found. Also, break out of the loop when you find a match.

OK — I don't use the [[ command because its rules are screwball (to my way of thinking).  It doesn't behave like a normal command.  I dislike that.
